# How many passes does gcc make over the input source code?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

As per this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45519450/8600195) answer, modern compilers just do a single pass.  Assuming GCC to be a modern one, why does the [following simple program](http://cpp.sh/9trfq) give me an error saying that `test()` was not declared in this scope:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str="Naggy";
    test(str);

    cout<<str<<"\n";
}

void test(string& str) {
    str="Rathore";
}
```

I know this error can be easily resolved by having a function prototype for `test()` above `main()`; or by declaring and defining `test()` before `main()`.  However, I am *not* asking for a workaround - I am asking *why does the compiler not detect* that I have declared and defined `test()` at a later stage in the program?

From what I remember from having learnt in school, many assemblers parse the input code twice; but if GCC (and maybe its assembler?) does that only once, then why doesn't it take such *forward references* into account?  Or, am I missing something?

Thanks.

Note: cpp.sh does use GCC as noted [here](http://cpp.sh/v03/about.html).

Edit: As per C++ rules, we need to declare the stuff before we use it.  If (and when) the assembler does pass 1, does it not find out (and make a note) of the stuff that has been declared (like `test()` in this case) and then use that later in pass 2 to to resolve the apparent forward references?  Or, does this responsibility *NOT* lie with the assembler?

Comment: How can you tell `test` is defined when you first reach it if you haven't seen it and you are only doing a single pass?

Comment: That's not a compiler issue. The C++ language says that you have to declare stuff before you use it. How many times the compiler reads your source is irrelevant here.

Comment: @NathanOliver, editing the question to answer that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)

Comment: To add to the confusion [the C++ standard requires 2 passes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767626/two-phase-lookup-explanation-needed) in certain situations.

Comment: @nwp: Not really. Two phase lookup doesn't require two passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is *because* it only does a single pass. To support a function defined after it's used, it would have to make two passes: Pass 1 finds all the function signatures, pass 2 checks the calls against all the signatures to determine if the function is defined.

The specification of C++ was written with this in mind, which is why it requires all functions and classes to be defined before they're referenced.

Assemblers are often able to handle forward references with a single pass because the language is simpler. When they encounter an unknown identifier, they don't need to know what its declaration is -- it's just an address. They can leave a placeholder in the output data, and when they get to the definition they can update the placeholder.

C++ is more complicated, because a name can refer to a function or a class, and if it's a function there can be multiple overloads. Parsing the use of the name depends on what it names, so it's not really feasible to leave a placeholder until the definition is found.

Comment: So, if I get it right, the assembler makes two passes, while the compiler makes just a single pass.  If this is right, then does the assembler not make a note of this when it makes two passes?

Comment: Sir, I agree with your answer.... Even though it is not directly said in standards document, it seems like C++ standard allows multipass compilers. Is my assumption correct? please look into below link and search for "multi-pass" ...... http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf

Comment: @J.Doe Why do you put the same comment under every answer? And why do you suddenly talk about assemblers? They have nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @nwp, 1. because I have the same question to ask in each case (since their answers do not talk about it (at least in a way I understand)).  And 2. assemblers, since I wonder why the assembler does not do it if it does two passes.

Comment: They're different languages, they have different rules.

Comment: @J.Doe I've updated the answer to explain the difference between what can be done in C++ versus assembler.

Answer (score 1):

C++ language is much more complex than you think... for example there are cases in which this kind if "look ahead" is indeed performed:

```
struct Foo {
    void baz() {
        bar(); // ok, even if bar comes later
    }
    void bar() {
        printf("Hello, world.\n");
    }
};
```

The compiler is giving an error in your case because C++ rules say so. Many parts of C++ are logical, but many also are not logical at all.

Consider that C++ has even a rule so complex that requires the compiler to read an **unlimited** number of tokens before it can decide what is the semantic meaning of the very first of them (the dreaded "[most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)" rule).

With C++ the only safe approach sometimes to just learn the rules: don't try too hard to always find a logic, may be there's none.

Comment: So, if I get it right, the assembler makes two passes, while the compiler makes just a single pass. If this is right, then does the assembler not make a note of this when it makes two passes?